# Why my springboot application keep launch on eclipse as remote debug?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

My latest eclipse does not start my spring boot application use maven in configuration: spring-boot:run
It keeps connect to port 5005 as remote application but I do not have a tomcat server running.
Why my spring-boot application keeps launch on eclipse as remote debug?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vv5cIJtC3ruvXnoyA7sHkng7cW-cW0fT/view?usp=sharing

Appreciate if anything, anyone around after they modified it.

Amy

Start, stop, .m2, etc.